# multiple mediaplayer sound crash android

Tags: java, android, crash, android-mediaplayer, audio

I have multiple sounds i would like loaded

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsnd);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsnd2);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsnd3);
```

ect.

I have sound starts within clicklisteners

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
mp.start(); 

}};
```

It has to be final as mp.start(); won't be seen within listeners
Is there a way to switch between the different sounds as mediaplayer will crash the app
if I use this more than once

Can set tag/ get tag be used if possible to make the switch?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The MediaPlayer has a state machine that I believe you are ignoring. The static create methods are a shortcut for one-time deals. If you want the MediaPlayer to be used more than once, do something like this:

```
final MediaPlayer mp1 = new MediaPlayer();

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        try {
            mp1.reset();
            mp1.setDataSource(YourClass.this,
                Uri.parse("android.resource://com.your.package/" + R.raw.testsnd);
            mp1.prepare();
            mp1.start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

It should be trivial to replace your package and class names, and also to extrapolate the idea for multiple MediaPlayers. Chances are you only need one at any given time unless the sounds can be played at the same time. Also, don't forget to call release() when you are done.

If the sounds are brief, you may want to look into using [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

I can`t understand why you do things like that, can you post more of your code? But if you need to play three sounds from your MediaPlayer instance you can try this:

```
private final MediaPlayer mpSound1;
private final MediaPlayer mpSound2;
private final MediaPlayer mpSound3;

private void playSound1(){
  try{
     if(mpSound1==null)
        mpSound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsnd);
     mpSound1.start();
  }catch(Exception ex){
     mpSound1 = null;
  }
}

private void playSound2(){
  try{
     if(mpSound2==null)
        mpSound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsnd2);
     mpSound2.start();
  }catch(Exception ex){
     mpSound2 = null;
  }
}

private void playSound3(){
  try{
     if(mpSound3==null)
        mpSound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsnd3);
     mpSound3.start();
  }catch(Exception ex){
     mpSound3 = null;
  }
}
```